# Android - Restore application after crash

Tags: android

I have an app which, if it gets closed by the user and restarted again, moves right back to the activity where it was closed.
Now I want to add a functionality, so when the app crashes, it clears the data and restarts the application from the first activity.
My idea is that I have a property "isClosedCorrectly" which I set to false as soon as the application starts. I set it to true when the application is closed correctly.
When I start my app, I look into this property and I'll make an action depending on what I want.
My question is: When isClosedCorrectly is set to TRUE? Can I handle this?

Comment: What is the error  output in the log?

Comment: This approach is not fool proof, instead you must use proper test cases to test your code. However having said that, you can leverage the activity life cycle methods, to achieve what you intend.

Comment: the easy way: fix an error and do not allow to your application crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean with "closed correctly", but I assume you mean unhandled Exception throws.

What comes to my mind is the chance to instantiate a UncaughtExceptionHandler

```
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

            }
    );
```

Using this you can have the app notice when something bad is happening, something that would lead your app to crash.

I'd write some sort of "log" in this uncaughtException method, a file with simple data like "true" or "false".

Whenever you open the app you might read the file's content and know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no application-level lifecycle method that will tell you when your application is "closed" correctly. One of the biggest reasons is that there really is no such thing as correctly "closing" an application.

When a user leaves your application, the currently running Activity goes into the background and remains in memory. This way if the user decides to come back to your application, they don't need to wait for it to do a cold start again.

If you want to go down this route, you have a few options:

- Log every Activity's `onStop()` in some way that makes sense to your application, and use the information of whether an Activity's `onStop()` was called to determine if it was "closed".
- Default to "true" for your `isClosedCorrectly` when your application starts to assume that everything that isn't "incorrect" is "correct." Then, when your application crashes set `isClosedCorrectly` to false. You can intercept crashes using [`Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))